# VB 2013 Textbox: Replace space with "+"

Tags: vb.net, web, browser, textbox, space

I am creating a web browser in VB 2013 Pro and I have one text box accepting the URLs and searches. Right now this is what code I have for the go button:

```
'Check if text is a search term.
    If TextBox1.Text.Contains(".") Then
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
        Timer2.Start()
    Else
        TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "+")
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(My.Settings.search & TextBox1.Text)
    End If
```

I have when the go button is clicked, it checks to see if there is a "." in the textbox, this is because searches usually don't have periods in them, URLs do. So if it finds a textbox with a period in it, it will attempt to navigate to it. If it does not find a period in the textbox, it will attempt a search. In the "my.settings.search" I have "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=". I do not know why it is not replacing the spaces with a "+" so the browser can actually navigate and search it. I did search on Google, and all the answers I found just say to use the replace command like I did, and just put a space at the character to replace. Timer2 is just telling the app to put the current URL in the textbox and the application title.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: `Replace` is a **function** not a method.  you have to assign the return for it to work like you want

Comment: Wow, how did I forget that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the replace function is non-destructive, it returns the modified String.

Try TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ","+")

Answer (score 0):

UrlEncode the box instead. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Your project will need to reference System.Web

```
NextPage.NavigateUrl = "~/Finish?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(destinationURL)
```